# pyside2-uic null bytes in output

Tags: python, python-3.7, pyside2

I'm trying to convert Qt .ui files made using Qt Designer with pyside2-uic but the output starts with 2 garbage bytes then every other byte is a null.

Here's the start of the output:

> FF FE 23 00 20 00 2D 00 2A 00 2D 00 20 00 63 00 6F 00 64 00 69 00 6E 00 67 00 3A 00 20 00 75 00 74 00 66 00 2D 00 38 00 20 00 2D 00 2A 00 2D 00 0D 00 0A 00 0D 00 0A 00 23 00 20 00 46 00 6F 00

If I remove the first 2 bytes and all the nulls the it works as expected.

I'm using Python 3.7 and the newest version of pyside2, is there any way to get pyside2-uic to output a valid file without having to run it through another script to pull out all the garbage?

Comment: How strange, I am using python 3.7.1 with pyside2 5.11.2 and it works correctly in Linux, you could give more details of your environment.

Comment: Windows 10, Python 3.7.0, pyside2 5.11.2. And I'm just running the command from the command line, "pyside2-uic myui.ui > myui.py". I'll try updating to python 3.7.1 when I can.

Comment: I use `pyside2-uic myui.ui -o myui.py -x`

Comment: Well I just tried running the same command as you and it worked then I tried my old way again and that also worked. It seems to have been magically fixed. Only thing I can think of was restarting my computer fixed it but I don't really see how that could be.

Comment: Have you deleted the .py file after executing my command ?. If there is no problem I recommend you eliminate your question as it is irreproducible, making it off-topic in SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug(?) only occurs when pyside2-uic is run in powershell and the output is redirected to a file.

If using powershell use the -o option to specify an output file. Both methods work fine from a normal command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, issue seems to be UTF-8 encoding (when using -o), vs. UTF-16 LE (output redirect in PowerShell).

This also matches to above ... every byte has a 00 with it (16 bit vs. 8 bit).

Answer (score 0):

In `pyside2-uic mainwindow.ui -o MainWindow.py`

Use `-o` instead of `>`